# How to add new column in existing View in SQL-Server 2014 using Alter

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, alter

I have created a view that is based on another view and a table. I want to add new column of type varchar. I did like below, But getting syntax error?
I am new to SQL, So,could not understand

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[MyView]
ADD New_Col varchar(10) null 
GO
```

Comment: What's the error message? Help us help you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by creating a view based on another view but if you views are nested you have a performance issue. Nested views seem so logical but in reality they are just awful. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/

Answer (score 33):

you have to write the entire view again and just add or omit what you want to change

for example your view is now :

```
create view myView as
  select field1
  from table1
```

and now you want to add a field called `New_Col` than you write this :

```
alter view myView as
  select field1,
         New_Col
  from table1
```

Comment: can't we write a script for adding a column for all the views in a database?

Comment: @manikantanvsr Yes, you could by using select * or by using select table_name.* However, remember that the view won't automatically pick up new columns from the table. After you alter the table, you'll need to refresh the view using SP_REFRESHVIEW "view_name".

Comment: @AdityaKar I will never recommend `select *` to anyone, that is just bad practice. And certainly not in a view !

Answer (score 3):

You can't alter a view like a table. You have to script the view as Alter, and then alter the select statement that generates the view.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a view’s SELECT statement with the ALTER VIEW statement.
Instead, you must drop and re-create the view.

Comment: There is no need to drop the view, you can use `alter view` but not like you would with a table. See my answer

Answer (score -1):

```
if not exists(select * from sys.columns where (name='columnToBeAdd') and object_id=object_id('YourViewName'))
begin
Declare @ViewDefinition varchar(max) 
select @ViewDefinition=definition from sys.objects o join sys.sql_modules m on m.object_id=o.object_id
where o.object_id=object_id('YourViewName') 
and o.type ='V'
select 
@ViewDefinition=REPLACE( replace(@ViewDefinition,'CREATE ','Alter '),' Create ' ,' Alter ' ) 
Select @ViewDefinition=REPLACE( @ViewDefinition, 'From ',', YourTableName.columnToBeAdd + CHAR(13) +  ' From ' )

exec( @ViewDefinition)
end
```

Comment: Can you use the built-in formatting to make it more readable?