# How to write a script to add column to multiple views using single script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-column

I am looking a script which allows me to add single column to multiple views.
I am using SQL Server.
For Ex.
I have view1, view2, view3 with column1, column2.

I need to add column3 in all the views
How can I do that ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  `alter view`.  One at a time.

Comment: Are your views fed from an underlying table which has been altered?

Comment: Use Excel or unix (awk, etc.) to generate the script to save you time.

Comment: If your views are indeed looking at altered tables i.e. using a select * from YourTable definition, then you could alter each table using a script, and then recompile the affected views by using the sp_recompile

Comment: `alter view` does not works like `alter table` You need to write the entire view again and then add your new column. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535278/how-to-add-new-column-in-existing-view-in-sql-server-2014-using-alter/39535322#39535322). So its not going to be easy to generate something for that