# How to add a column to an existing view from a table?

Tags: sql-server

I need to add a column to the view but I cannot find the right way to this. Please provide me with a proper syntax. 
I need to add the column "NextFeeDate" from table "T_atmcardparam" to the "atmcardparam".

```
ALTER VIEW view_name
("column 1", "col 2", "col3", "col4")
SELECT ("col5", "col6", "col7", "col8")
FROM table_name
```

I found this syntax online but don't know how to implement it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535278/how-to-add-new-column-in-existing-view-in-sql-server-2014-using-alter

Comment: Add it to the columns in the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `alter view` syntax to add a column - you just recreate it with the new query using the `or replace` clause. E.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_name
("column 1", "col 2", "col3", "col4")
AS 
SELECT ("col5", "col6", "col7", "col8")
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the entire view again and just add or omit what you want to change....

for the first time you have to create the view..

```
create view view_name as
  select field_name
  from table_name
```

and then you have to add a column in table using alter the view

```
alter view view_name as
      select field_name,
      field_name2
      from table_name
```

2nd Option is that you have to open script the view as Alter, and then alter the select statement that generates the view.

For more info....try this...https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp